# python scraping school's webpage which requires user login

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, forms

I'm using python to scrape my school's webpage, but in order to do that I needed to simulate a user login first. here is my code:

```
import requests, lxml.html
s = requests.session()

url = "https://my.emich.edu"

login = s.get(url)

login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]:x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
form["username"] = "myusernamge"
form["password"] = "mypassword"
form["submit"] = "LOGIN"

response = s.post("https://netid.emich.edu/cas/loginservice=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.emich.edu%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin",form)
response = s.get("http://my.emich.edu")

f = open("result.html","w")
f.write(response.text)

print response.text
```

i am expecting that response.text will give me my own student account page instead of that it gives me a log in requirement page. Can any one help me with this issue?
BTW this is not a homework

Comment: Can you compare the request you've made with an actual request performed by your browser? Have you missed any form fields?

Comment: @paradox what happens if you request the homepage again after you have successfully posted? How do you know that your post has been successful?

Comment: @paradox -- also, isn't the post url https://my.emich.edu/c/portal/login ?

Comment: @JoshLee  I've compared my request with the actual request by browser, the only form data i'm missing is submit:LOGIN, after i added it to my form dictionary, it still giving me the login page

Comment: @David542 thank you for pointing that out! I've requested the hompage again after posted form, and I still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here, and I think your requests approach can be made much easier by logging in manually and copying over the headers.

1. Use a python scripting package like http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ to scrape the site.
2. Use a browser-emulater such as http://casperjs.org/. Using this you can basically do anything you'd be able to do in a browser.
3. My suggestion here would be to go to the website, log in, and then open the developer console and copy those headers/cookies into your requests headers/cookies. This way you can just hardcode the 'already-authenticated request' and it will work fine. Note that this method is the least reliable for doing robust, everyday scraping, but if you're looking for something that will be the quickest to implement and will work until the authentication runs out, use this method.

Also, you need the request the logged-in homepage (again) after you successfully do the post.

Comment: i've tried mechanize and its still not giving me expected result